# Scalajs: adding a border to a canvas

Tags: scala.js

I've been trying to add a border to a canvas in Scalajs. I mean add a border to the Canvas itself not add a border to an object on the canvas. I am hence looking for methods on the Canvas itself not on the Graphics context from the canvas. So I have the following code which paints a brown square in the top right of the canvas:

```scala
val can: html.Canvas = document.createElement("canvas").asInstanceOf[html.Canvas]      
document.body.appendChild(can)      
val width = window.innerWidth -20
val height = (window.innerHeight - 80)      
can.width = width.toInt
can.height = height.toInt
//val dec = new raw.CSSStyleDeclaration()
val gc = can.getContext("2d").asInstanceOf[raw.CanvasRenderingContext2D]
//display.can.setProperty("borderColor", Colour.black.hexStr)
gc.fillStyle = "#AA5500"
gc.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200)       
//dec.borderWidth = "2"
//display.can.style = dec
```

Looking at the documentation  it seems I need to create a `CSSStyleDeclaration`. But as soon as I uncomment the `val dec = ...` line, I get a `TypeError: Illegal constructor`, when I run it in the Web console. Chrome's console points to the following javascript line as the problem:

```js
new $g["CSSStyleDeclaration"]();
```

Edit: this works, but I'd prefer to use the proper ScalaJs methods rather resorting to dynamic:

```
can.asInstanceOf[scalajs.js.Dynamic].style = "border:2px solid black;"
```

Comment: Is it totally out of the question to style it with normal CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to do the stroke with strokeRect.  The canvas.strokeRect splits the stroke so that it falls partially outside and partially inside. There's an adjustment to keep all the stroke inside the canvas.  You should be able to convert this to ScalaJs.

```js
var can = document.createElement("canvas");     
document.body.appendChild(can);
var width = window.innerWidth -20;
var height = (window.innerHeight - 80);    
can.width = width;
can.height = height;
//val dec = new raw.CSSStyleDeclaration()
var gc = can.getContext("2d");
//display.can.setProperty("borderColor", Colour.black.hexStr)
gc.fillStyle = "#AA5500";
gc.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);   
//dec.borderWidth = "2"
//display.can.style = dec

gc.strokeStyle = "#000000";
var strokeSize = 10;
var halfStroke = strokeSize / 2;
gc.lineWidth = strokeSize;
gc.strokeRect(0 + halfStroke,0 + halfStroke,width-strokeSize,height-strokeSize);
```

Comment: Apologies but this is not a JavaScript problem. I have edited out the Javascript and Canvas tags, that I had deliberately not included originally, but had been edited in by someone else.

Comment: @RichOliver from you're code I can see that canvas properties and methods are available to ScalaJs. Given that you should be able to set context.lineWidth and call context.strokeRect(leftX, topY, rightX, bottomY).

Comment: I've edited the question again for more clarity. I'm trying to put a border on the canvas itself, not put a border on an object created through the graphics context, which works fine.